# I am having trouble with handling different error pages for my application

Tags: java, spring

I am having trouble handling different error codes with my application. I have followed [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-error-page) and it worked for a few hours. But after taking a break and getting back it seemed to have stopped working. Now every error (including 404 and 500 which I have seperate html files for) goes to the default error.html I have set **application.properties** as such:

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.38:5432/cms_database
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password

server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
server.error.path=/error
```

My **ErrorController**:

```
@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);

        if (status != null) {
            Integer statusCode = Integer.valueOf(status.toString());

            if(statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
                return "error-404";
            }
            else if(statusCode == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
                return "error-500";
            }
        }
        return "error";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

After trying to debug it seems that the controller stops working at the @RequestMapping which doesnt get invoked at all & the rest of the code.

Any tips or help is appreciated. Any other info you need I am happy to provide.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I noticed that in my other controller **MainController** I had a method written:

```
@GetMapping("/error")
public String showError() {
    return "error";
}
```

whoops